# Mesa-18.1.6 'c compiler cannot create executables'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mesa, linux-from-scratch

so I have been trying to compile Mesa on BLFS 8.3 to no avail, and I am having issues trying to figure out what seems to be the issue. I am not quite understanding why it will not compile, when gcc is installed.

My current setup is LFS 8.3, using Parallels on macOS. Thank you very much for the help!!

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Mesa configure 18.1.6, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure CFLAGS=-O2 CXXFLAGS=-O2 LDFLAGS=-lLLVM --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-texture-float --enable-osmesa --enable-xa --enable-glx-tls --with-platforms=drm,x11,wayland --with-gallium-drivers=

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = boltOS
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.18.5
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Thu Oct 11 13:53:59 CDT 2018

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3414: checking build system type
configure:3428: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3448: checking host system type
configure:3461: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3481: checking target system type
configure:3494: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3537: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3605: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3616: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3671: result: yes
configure:3822: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3861: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3868: checking for gawk
configure:3884: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3895: result: gawk
configure:3906: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3928: result: yes
configure:3957: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3974: result: yes
configure:4063: checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format
configure:4066: result: yes
configure:4073: checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format
configure:4076: result: yes
configure:4084: checking how to create a ustar tar archive
configure:4095: tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
configure:4098: $? = 0
configure:4138: tardir=conftest.dir && eval tar --format=ustar -chf - "$tardir" >conftest.tar
configure:4141: $? = 0
configure:4145: tar -xf - <conftest.tar
configure:4148: $? = 0
configure:4150: cat conftest.dir/file
GrepMe
configure:4153: $? = 0
configure:4166: result: gnutar
configure:4237: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:4254: result: yes
configure:4278: checking for style of include used by make
configure:4306: result: GNU
configure:4377: checking for gcc
configure:4393: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4404: result: gcc
configure:4633: checking for C compiler version
configure:4642: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is 
NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
PURPOSE.

configure:4653: $? = 0
configure:4642: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmpx --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC) 
configure:4653: $? = 0
configure:4642: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4653: $? = 1
configure:4642: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4653: $? = 1
configure:4673: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4695: gcc -O2  -lLLVM conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVM
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4699: $? = 1
configure:4737: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Mesa"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mesa"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "18.1.6"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Mesa 18.1.6"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mesa"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "mesa"
| #define VERSION "18.1.6"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4742: error: in `/sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6':
configure:4744: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_AMDGPU_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_AMDGPU_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_AMDGPU_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_AMDGPU_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_ANDROID_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ANDROID_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ANDROID_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ANDROID_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=-O2
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX11_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX11_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=-O2
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DRI2PROTO_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_DRI2PROTO_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_DRI2PROTO_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_DRI2PROTO_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_DRIGL_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_DRIGL_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_DRIGL_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_DRIGL_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_ETNAVIV_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ETNAVIV_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ETNAVIV_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ETNAVIV_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_EXPAT_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_EXPAT_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_EXPAT_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_EXPAT_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_FREEDRENO_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FREEDRENO_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FREEDRENO_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_FREEDRENO_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLPROTO_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLPROTO_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLPROTO_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLPROTO_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLVND_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLVND_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLVND_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLVND_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_I915_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_I915_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_I915_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_I915_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-lLLVM
ac_cv_env_LIBDRM_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBDRM_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBDRM_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBDRM_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBELF_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBELF_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBELF_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBELF_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBUNWIND_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBUNWIND_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBUNWIND_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBUNWIND_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_NOUVEAU_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_NOUVEAU_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_NOUVEAU_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_NOUVEAU_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_NVVIEUX_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_NVVIEUX_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_NVVIEUX_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_NVVIEUX_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_OMX_BELLAGIO_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_OMX_BELLAGIO_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_OMX_BELLAGIO_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_OMX_BELLAGIO_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_OMX_TIZONIA_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_OMX_TIZONIA_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_OMX_TIZONIA_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_OMX_TIZONIA_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_PTHREADSTUBS_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_PTHREADSTUBS_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_PTHREADSTUBS_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_PTHREADSTUBS_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_RADEON_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_RADEON_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_RADEON_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_RADEON_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SELINUX_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_SIMPENROSE_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SIMPENROSE_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SIMPENROSE_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_SIMPENROSE_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_VALGRIND_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VALGRIND_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VALGRIND_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VALGRIND_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_VA_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VA_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VA_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VA_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_VC5_SIMULATOR_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VC5_SIMULATOR_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VC5_SIMULATOR_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VC5_SIMULATOR_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_VDPAU_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VDPAU_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VDPAU_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VDPAU_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_VL_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_VL_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_VL_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_VL_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_CLIENT_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_CLIENT_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_CLIENT_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_CLIENT_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SCANNER_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SCANNER_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SCANNER_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SCANNER_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SERVER_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SERVER_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SERVER_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_WAYLAND_SERVER_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI2_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI2_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI2_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI2_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XF86VIDMODE_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XF86VIDMODE_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XF86VIDMODE_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XF86VIDMODE_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XLIBGL_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XLIBGL_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XLIBGL_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XLIBGL_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XVMC_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XVMC_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XVMC_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XVMC_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ZLIB_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
am_cv_prog_tar_ustar=gnutar

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMDGPU_CFLAGS=''
AMDGPU_LIBS=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
ANDROID_CFLAGS=''
ANDROID_LIBS=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='gawk'
BSYMBOLIC=''
BUILD_SHARED_FALSE=''
BUILD_SHARED_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-O2'
CLANG_RESOURCE_DIR=''
CLOCK_LIB=''
CLOVER_STD_OVERRIDE=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX11_CXXFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS='-O2'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
D3D_DRIVER_INSTALL_DIR=''
DEFINES=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DLOPEN_LIBS=''
DRI2PROTO_CFLAGS=''
DRI2PROTO_LIBS=''
DRIGL_CFLAGS=''
DRIGL_LIBS=''
DRI_DRIVER_INSTALL_DIR=''
DRI_DRIVER_SEARCH_DIR=''
DRI_LIB_DEPS=''
DRI_PC_REQ_PRIV=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGL_CFLAGS=''
EGL_LIB_DEPS=''
EGL_NATIVE_PLATFORM=''
EGREP=''
ETNAVIV_CFLAGS=''
ETNAVIV_LIBS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPAT_CFLAGS=''
EXPAT_LIBS=''
FGREP=''
FREEDRENO_CFLAGS=''
FREEDRENO_LIBS=''
GALLIUM_PIPE_LOADER_DEFINES=''
GBM_PC_LIB_PRIV=''
GBM_PC_REQ_PRIV=''
GC_SECTIONS=''
GEN_ASM_OFFSETS_FALSE=''
GEN_ASM_OFFSETS_TRUE=''
GLESv1_CM_LIB_DEPS=''
GLESv1_CM_PC_LIB_PRIV=''
GLESv2_LIB_DEPS=''
GLESv2_PC_LIB_PRIV=''
GLPROTO_CFLAGS=''
GLPROTO_LIBS=''
GLVND_CFLAGS=''
GLVND_LIBS=''
GLX_TLS=''
GL_LIB=''
GL_LIB_DEPS=''
GL_PC_CFLAGS=''
GL_PC_LIB_PRIV=''
GL_PC_REQ_PRIV=''
GL_PKGCONF_LIB=''
GREP=''
HAVE_AARCH64_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_AARCH64_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_AMD_DRIVERS_FALSE=''
HAVE_AMD_DRIVERS_TRUE=''
HAVE_ANDROID_FALSE=''
HAVE_ANDROID_TRUE=''
HAVE_APPLEDRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_APPLEDRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_ARM_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_ARM_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_BROADCOM_DRIVERS_FALSE=''
HAVE_BROADCOM_DRIVERS_TRUE=''
HAVE_CLOVER_FALSE=''
HAVE_CLOVER_ICD_FALSE=''
HAVE_CLOVER_ICD_TRUE=''
HAVE_CLOVER_TRUE=''
HAVE_COMMON_OSMESA_FALSE=''
HAVE_COMMON_OSMESA_TRUE=''
HAVE_COMPAT_SYMLINKS_FALSE=''
HAVE_COMPAT_SYMLINKS_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRI2_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRI2_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRI3_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRI3_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRICOMMON_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRICOMMON_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRISW_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRISW_KMS_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRISW_KMS_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRISW_TRUE=''
HAVE_DRI_GLX_FALSE=''
HAVE_DRI_GLX_TRUE=''
HAVE_EGL_FALSE=''
HAVE_EGL_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_COMPUTE_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_COMPUTE_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_ETNAVIV_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_ETNAVIV_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_EXTRA_HUD_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_EXTRA_HUD_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_FREEDRENO_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_FREEDRENO_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_I915_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_I915_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_IMX_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_IMX_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_LLVMPIPE_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_LLVMPIPE_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_LLVM_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_LLVM_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_NOUVEAU_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_NOUVEAU_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_OSMESA_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_OSMESA_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_PL111_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_PL111_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_R300_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_R300_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_R600_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_R600_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_RADEONSI_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_RADEONSI_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SOFTPIPE_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SOFTPIPE_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_STATIC_TARGETS_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_STATIC_TARGETS_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SVGA_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SVGA_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SWRAST_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SWRAST_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SWR_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_SWR_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_TEGRA_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_TEGRA_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_TESTS_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_TESTS_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VC4_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VC4_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VC5_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VC5_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VIRGL_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_VIRGL_TRUE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_XLIB_GLX_FALSE=''
HAVE_GALLIUM_XLIB_GLX_TRUE=''
HAVE_GBM_FALSE=''
HAVE_GBM_TRUE=''
HAVE_GLX_FALSE=''
HAVE_GLX_TRUE=''
HAVE_I915_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_I915_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_I965_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_I965_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_INTEL_DRIVERS_FALSE=''
HAVE_INTEL_DRIVERS_TRUE=''
HAVE_INTEL_VULKAN_FALSE=''
HAVE_INTEL_VULKAN_TRUE=''
HAVE_LD_DYNAMIC_LIST_FALSE=''
HAVE_LD_DYNAMIC_LIST_TRUE=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_FALSE=''
HAVE_LD_VERSION_SCRIPT_TRUE=''
HAVE_LIBDRM_FALSE=''
HAVE_LIBDRM_TRUE=''
HAVE_LIBSENSORS_FALSE=''
HAVE_LIBSENSORS_TRUE=''
HAVE_LMSENSORS_FALSE=''
HAVE_LMSENSORS_TRUE=''
HAVE_NOUVEAU_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_NOUVEAU_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_ES1_FALSE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_ES1_TRUE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_ES2_FALSE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_ES2_TRUE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_FALSE=''
HAVE_OPENGL_TRUE=''
HAVE_OSMESA_FALSE=''
HAVE_OSMESA_TRUE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_FALSE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_TRUE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_DRM_FALSE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_DRM_TRUE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_SURFACELESS_FALSE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_SURFACELESS_TRUE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_FALSE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_TRUE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_X11_FALSE=''
HAVE_PLATFORM_X11_TRUE=''
HAVE_PPC64LE_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_PPC64LE_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_R200_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_R200_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_RADEON_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_RADEON_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_RADEON_VULKAN_FALSE=''
HAVE_RADEON_VULKAN_TRUE=''
HAVE_SHARED_GLAPI_FALSE=''
HAVE_SHARED_GLAPI_TRUE=''
HAVE_SPARC_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_SPARC_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_STD_CXX11_FALSE=''
HAVE_STD_CXX11_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_NINE_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_NINE_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_OMX_BELLAGIO_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_OMX_BELLAGIO_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_OMX_TIZONIA_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_OMX_TIZONIA_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_VA_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_VA_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_VDPAU_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_VDPAU_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_XA_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_XA_TRUE=''
HAVE_ST_XVMC_FALSE=''
HAVE_ST_XVMC_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWRAST_DRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWRAST_DRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWR_AVX2_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWR_AVX2_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWR_AVX_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWR_AVX_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWR_BUILTIN_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWR_BUILTIN_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWR_KNL_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWR_KNL_TRUE=''
HAVE_SWR_SKX_FALSE=''
HAVE_SWR_SKX_TRUE=''
HAVE_VULKAN_COMMON_FALSE=''
HAVE_VULKAN_COMMON_TRUE=''
HAVE_WINDOWSDRI_FALSE=''
HAVE_WINDOWSDRI_TRUE=''
HAVE_X86_64_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_X86_64_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_X86_ASM_FALSE=''
HAVE_X86_ASM_TRUE=''
HAVE_XF86VIDMODE=''
HAVE_XF86VIDMODE_FALSE=''
HAVE_XF86VIDMODE_TRUE=''
HAVE_XLIB_GLX_FALSE=''
HAVE_XLIB_GLX_TRUE=''
I915_CFLAGS=''
I915_LIBS=''
INDENT=''
INDENT_FLAGS=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-lLLVM'
LD_BUILD_ID=''
LD_NO_UNDEFINED=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBATOMIC_LIBS=''
LIBCLC_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBCLC_LIBEXECDIR=''
LIBDRM_CFLAGS=''
LIBDRM_LIBS=''
LIBELF_CFLAGS=''
LIBELF_LIBS=''
LIBGLVND_DATADIR=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBSENSORS_LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBUNWIND_CFLAGS=''
LIBUNWIND_LIBS=''
LIB_DIR=''
LIB_EXT=''
LIPO=''
LLVM_CFLAGS=''
LLVM_CONFIG=''
LLVM_CXXFLAGS=''
LLVM_INCLUDEDIR=''
LLVM_LDFLAGS=''
LLVM_LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MSVC2013_COMPAT_CFLAGS=''
MSVC2013_COMPAT_CXXFLAGS=''
NEED_GALLIUM_VL_FALSE=''
NEED_GALLIUM_VL_TRUE=''
NEED_GALLIUM_VL_WINSYS_FALSE=''
NEED_GALLIUM_VL_WINSYS_TRUE=''
NEED_KHRPLATFORM_FALSE=''
NEED_KHRPLATFORM_TRUE=''
NEED_LIBMESA_FALSE=''
NEED_LIBMESA_TRUE=''
NEED_MEGADRIVER_FALSE=''
NEED_MEGADRIVER_TRUE=''
NEED_OPENGL_COMMON_FALSE=''
NEED_OPENGL_COMMON_TRUE=''
NEED_RADEON_DRM_WINSYS_FALSE=''
NEED_RADEON_DRM_WINSYS_TRUE=''
NEED_WINSYS_XLIB_FALSE=''
NEED_WINSYS_XLIB_TRUE=''
NINE_MAJOR=''
NINE_MINOR=''
NINE_PATCH=''
NINE_VERSION=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NOUVEAU_CFLAGS=''
NOUVEAU_LIBS=''
NVVIEUX_CFLAGS=''
NVVIEUX_LIBS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OMX_BELLAGIO_CFLAGS=''
OMX_BELLAGIO_LIBS=''
OMX_BELLAGIO_LIB_INSTALL_DIR=''
OMX_TIZONIA_CFLAGS=''
OMX_TIZONIA_LIBS=''
OMX_TIZONIA_LIB_INSTALL_DIR=''
OPENCL_LIBNAME=''
OPENCL_VERSION=''
OSMESA_LIB=''
OSMESA_LIB_DEPS=''
OSMESA_PC_LIB_PRIV=''
OSMESA_PC_REQ=''
OSMESA_VERSION=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='mesa'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mesa'
PACKAGE_NAME='Mesa'
PACKAGE_STRING='Mesa 18.1.6'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='mesa'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='18.1.6'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
POSIX_SHELL=''
PTHREADSTUBS_CFLAGS=''
PTHREADSTUBS_LIBS=''
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
PWR8_CFLAGS=''
PYTHON2=''
RADEON_CFLAGS=''
RADEON_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
RM=''
SED=''
SELINUX_CFLAGS=''
SELINUX_LIBS=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SIMPENROSE_CFLAGS=''
SIMPENROSE_LIBS=''
SSE41_CFLAGS=''
SSE41_SUPPORTED_FALSE=''
SSE41_SUPPORTED_TRUE=''
STRIP=''
SWR_AVX2_CXXFLAGS=''
SWR_AVX_CXXFLAGS=''
SWR_INVALID_LLVM_VERSION_FALSE=''
SWR_INVALID_LLVM_VERSION_TRUE=''
SWR_KNL_CXXFLAGS=''
SWR_SKX_CXXFLAGS=''
USE_LIBGLVND_FALSE=''
USE_LIBGLVND_TRUE=''
USE_VC4_SIMULATOR_FALSE=''
USE_VC4_SIMULATOR_TRUE=''
USE_VC5_SIMULATOR_FALSE=''
USE_VC5_SIMULATOR_TRUE=''
VALGRIND_CFLAGS=''
VALGRIND_LIBS=''
VA_CFLAGS=''
VA_LIBS=''
VA_LIB_INSTALL_DIR=''
VA_MAJOR=''
VA_MINOR=''
VC5_SIMULATOR_CFLAGS=''
VC5_SIMULATOR_LIBS=''
VDPAU_CFLAGS=''
VDPAU_LIBS=''
VDPAU_LIB_INSTALL_DIR=''
VDPAU_MAJOR=''
VDPAU_MINOR=''
VERSION='18.1.6'
VISIBILITY_CFLAGS=''
VISIBILITY_CXXFLAGS=''
VL_CFLAGS=''
VL_LIBS=''
VULKAN_ICD_INSTALL_DIR=''
WAYLAND_CLIENT_CFLAGS=''
WAYLAND_CLIENT_LIBS=''
WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_CFLAGS=''
WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_DATADIR=''
WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS_LIBS=''
WAYLAND_SCANNER=''
WAYLAND_SCANNER_CFLAGS=''
WAYLAND_SCANNER_LIBS=''
WAYLAND_SERVER_CFLAGS=''
WAYLAND_SERVER_LIBS=''
WNO_OVERRIDE_INIT=''
X11_INCLUDES=''
XA_MAJOR=''
XA_MINOR=''
XA_PATCH=''
XA_VERSION=''
XCB_DRI2_CFLAGS=''
XCB_DRI2_LIBS=''
XCB_DRI3_CFLAGS=''
XCB_DRI3_LIBS=''
XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_CFLAGS=''
XCB_DRI3_MODIFIERS_LIBS=''
XF86VIDMODE_CFLAGS=''
XF86VIDMODE_LIBS=''
XLIBGL_CFLAGS=''
XLIBGL_LIBS=''
XVMC_CFLAGS=''
XVMC_LIBS=''
XVMC_LIB_INSTALL_DIR=''
XVMC_MAJOR=''
XVMC_MINOR=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ZLIB_CFLAGS=''
ZLIB_LIBS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
acv_mako_found=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='tar --format=ustar -chf - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='tar -xf -'
ax_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
ifGNUmake=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /sources/xc/mesa-18.1.6/bin/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='/etc'
target='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_vendor='pc'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Mesa"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "mesa"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "18.1.6"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Mesa 18.1.6"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mesa"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "mesa"
#define VERSION "18.1.6"

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I had to recompile LLVM, there was an error when I initially compiled it, so I went through the process and it liked it.